# Why is neccesary the enum StringSplitOptions.None in the Split method to be able to pass an array?

Tags: c#, split

I was wondering why `StringSplitOptions.None` (or another kind of option in the enum) is necessary to be able to pass an array to the `Split` method.

```
string[] lines = test.Split( new string[] { "\n", "," }, StringSplitOptions.None );
```

Notice that I can't do

```
string[] lines = test.Split( new string[] { "\n", "," } );
```

I'd like to understand why it works like this

Comment: Because that's the way the designers of that method created it? Idk what other answer you'd expect.. The overloads simply don't exist.

Comment: what is wrong with string[] lines = test.Split('\n', ',');?

Comment: This may sound condescendant or rude, but it is not. It's because it was made like this. If you really want to dig yourself, feel free to read the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L1049)

Comment: Are you probably looking for `test.Split( new char[] { '\n', ',' } )`?

Comment: @Serge I thought that '\n' counts as a string instead of char but just notice it works perfectly, didn't know, thanks.

Comment: @Cid It's not rude, don't worry, I just was wondering why it was necessary to add the enum in order to be able to use `new string[]` , maybe there'd be a good reason for it. I didn't know that `\n` counts as one char tho. But I still find weird the fact that in order to add a `new string[]` you are forced to add a second parameter that does not seem to do anything

Comment: By the way if it's really bothering you, you can write your own extension method, such as : `public static string[] Split(this string str, String[] separator) { return str.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None); }` Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3qVdtH)

Comment: It seems that `.Split(char[], ...)` is by far more popular than `.Split(string[], ...)`, that's why  `.Split(char[], ...)`  has by far more overloads

Answer (score 0):

Specifies options for applicable Split method overloads, such as whether to omit empty substrings from the returned array or trim whitespace from substrings.

This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values.

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).